# Assigning coordinates to data of a different year in R?

Tags: r, coordinates, spatial, geostatistics

I have got a data frame of Germany from 2012 with 8187 rows for 8187 postal codes (and about 10 variables listed as columns), but with no coordinates. Additionally, I have got coordinates of a different shapefile with 8203 rows (also including mostly the same postal codes).

I need the correct coordinates of the 8203 cases to be assigned to the 8178 cases of the initial data frame.

The problem: The difference of correct assignments needed is not 8178 with 16 cases missing (8203 - 8187 = 16), it is more. There are some towns (with postal codes) of 2012 which are not listed in the more recent shapefile and vice versa.

(I) Perhaps the easiest solution would be to obtain the coordinates from 2012 (unprojected: `CRS("+init=epsg:4326")`). --> Does anybody know an open source platform for this purpose? And do they have exactly 8187 postal codes?

(II) Or: Does anybody have an experience with assigning coordinates from to a data set of a different year? - Or, should this be avoided in any way because of some slightly changing borders and coordinates (especially when the data should be mapped and visualized in polygons from 2012) and some towns not listed in the older "and" in the newer data set?

I would appreciate your expert advice on how to approach (and hopefully solve) this issue!

EDIT - MWE:

```
# data set from 2012
> df1
# A tibble: 9 x 4
     ID  PLZ5          Name  Var1
  <dbl> <dbl>         <chr> <dbl>
1     1  1067 Dresden 01067    40
2     2  1069 Dresden 01069   110
3   224  4571         Rötha     0
4   225  4574       Deutzen   120
5   226  4575 Neukieritzsch   144
6   262  4860        Torgau    23
7   263  4862     Mockrehna    57
8  8186 99996     Menteroda     0
9  8187 99998        Körner    26

# coordinates of recent shapefile   
> df2
# A tibble: 9 x 5
     ID  PLZ5          Name Longitude Latitude
  <dbl> <dbl>         <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1  1067 Dresden-01067  13.71832 51.06018
2     2  1069 Dresden-01069  13.73655 51.03994
3   224  4571        Roetha  12.47311 51.20390
4   225  4575 Neukieritzsch  12.41355 51.15278
5   260  4860        Torgau  12.94737 51.55790
6   261  4861     Bennewitz  13.00145 51.51125
7   262  4862     Mockrehna  12.83097 51.51125
8  8202 99996    Obermehler  10.59146 51.28864
9  8203 99998       Koerner  10.55294 51.21257
```

Hence,

```
4   225  4574       Deutzen   120
```

--> is not listed in df2 and:

```
6   261  4861     Bennewitz  13.00145 51.51125
```

--> is not listed in df1.

Any ideas concerning (I) and (II)?

Comment: Provide an example of your data https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi, does anybody have some experience with this issue?

Comment: If you don't provide an example of your data we cannot help you

Comment: It seems that you will have to find the coordinates of missing postcodes manually... Google will help you find these missing cities.